# How to optimize this Javascript code for a Paint App?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, processing

I'm working on a Paint App using Processing.js. Basically, when the mouse is dragged, `mouseX` and `mouseY` are saved in an array of objects called `data[]`. Afterwards the `paint()` function will run a loop that accesses every object of the `data[]` array and draws a line of `color(data[i].R,data[i].G,data[i].B)` and thickness `data[i].T` between the corresponding `data[i].mouseX and data[i].mouseY` coordinates. The problem is that the array keeps getting bigger the more you draw and in my case, when the length of the `data[]` array reaches ~800 elements it will start to lag, and keeps getting worse the more I keep drawing. Is there any tweak that will fix the lag or do I have to completely rethink the program?

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
 <script src="https://github.com/downloads/processing-js/processing-js/processing-1.4.1.min.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/processing" data-processing-target="targetcanvas">
void setup() {
  size(649, 600);
}
background(255,255,255);
var r=0;
var g=0;
var b=0;
var data = [];
var mousex;
var mousey;
var thickness=31;
var painting = false;
var counter=0;
var x;
var paint = function() {
    background(255, 255, 255);  
    for(var i=1;i<data.length;i++){
        if (data[i-1].mousex && data[i].mousex) {
      strokeWeight(data[i].T);
      stroke(data[i].R, data[i].G, data[i].B);
            line(data[i].mousex,data[i].mousey,data[i-1].mousex,data[i-1].mousey);
   fill(0,0,0);
   text(data.length,10,10);
        }
    };
};
mouseDragged = function(){
    painting = true;
    data.push({mousex: mouseX, mousey: mouseY, R:r, G:g, B:b, T:thickness});
    paint();
    counter++;
};
mouseReleased = function() {
    x=counter;
    counter=0;
    if(painting) {
        data.push({mousex: 0, mousey: 0});
    }
    painting = false;
};
mouseOut = function() { 
data.push({mousex: 0, mousey: 0});
}
</script>
 <center>
        <canvas id="targetcanvas"width="649" height="600" " style="border: 3px solid black; margin-top=100px;"></canvas>
 </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Open it with Chrome.

Comment: It's possible to share code better than just linking to it on Drive : http://jsbin.com/piraniyuzu/edit?html,output

Comment: Or create a stack-snippet. I don't check code on other users google drive

Comment: Ok I will keep that in mind.

Comment: Don't just "keep it in mind", fix the question. Otherwise it will be closed and deleted.

Comment: I edited the question and I hope it's acceptable.

Comment: I voted to reopen. Need 3 more votes to get it open again (I asked other to reopen too)

Comment: Thanks Alon Eitan.

Answer (score 0):

Is this Processing.js or P5.js? Either way, the answer is the same.

You basically have a spectrum of options:

**No data structures, no undo:** Instead of storing your shapes and whatnot in data structures, just draw them directly to the canvas whenever the user does something. You can use a `PGraphics` canvas, or you can just draw directly to the screen, if you get rid of the call to `background()`. Then you don't need any data structures. The downside of this is you won't be able to remove shapes once they're drawn.

**Some data structures, some undo:** If you needed to be able to undo some of the shapes, but not all of them, you could do a mix of the above approach and your current approach. Instead of storing everything in data structures, you would only store the last 1-10 or so shapes. The rest of the shapes would be drawn directly to the `PGraphics` buffer.

**Lots of data structure, lots of undo:** If you really needed to be able to undo all of the shapes, then you could still use the `PGraphics` approach, but only redraw all of the shapes when something was removed.